# Python doesn't know the class attributes, while Jupyter does

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter

I have this code from StatQuest channel. This code works in Jupyter, however when I run this in a `.py` file, it reports the error

> AttributeError: 'BasicNNTrain' object has no attribute 'w00'

This is the code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.optim import SGD

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


class BasicNNTrain(nn.Module):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w00 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.7), requires_grad=False)
        self.b00 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(-0.85), requires_grad=False)
        self.w01 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(-40.8), requires_grad=False)

        self.w10 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(12.6), requires_grad=False)
        self.b10 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0), requires_grad=False)
        self.w11 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(2.7), requires_grad=False)

        self.final_bias = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, input):
        input_to_top_relu = input * self.w00 + self.b00
        top_relu_output = F.relu(input_to_top_relu)
        scaled_top_relu_output = top_relu_output * self.w01

        input_to_bottom_relu = input * self.w10 + self.b10
        bottom_relu_output = F.relu(input_to_bottom_relu)
        scaled_bottom_relu_output = bottom_relu_output * self.w11

        input_to_final_relu = scaled_top_relu_output + scaled_bottom_relu_output + self.final_bias

        output = F.relu(input_to_final_relu)

        return output


model = BasicNNTrain()
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.data)

input_doses = torch.linspace(start=0, end=1, steps=11)
print(input_doses)

model(input_doses)
```

Comment: Please check the versions of torch for both the Jupyter and Python environments.  You can do that by inserting `print(torch.__version__)` after the initial install.  Then update the question with the result from each environment.  Also please make sure that you restart the kernel just before testing in Jupyter and run _only_ the code you've posted here.

Comment: "This code works in Jupyter" No, no it does not. The above code will give you the exact same error in a jupyter notebook. Please always make sure when you make a claim like this you reproduce the problem. Almost certainly, you have an old definition in some notebook sticking around, and you aren't actually using the above one. Please *verify* these claims by testing it out yourself in a fresh notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of the typo in `def __int__` ?

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I made this mistake after being a PHP and Laravel Developer for 13 years. I recently switched to Python and Machine Learning. Thanks.